# Duplicated payment methods field on checkout page [ woocommerce ]

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Having some problem setting up my woocommerce shop because of the checkout page.
The problem is that I'm facing duplicated payment methods that appear on BILLING Page and also ORDER & PAYMENT page.

I'm using a theme that haves a one page checkout.
If anyone can indicate how can i remove the links

Images that explain the the situation
https://i.stack.imgur.com/17eQW.png - Billing and shipping page that show the wrong placement of the field
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD3Wl.png - the payment page that show the right and wrong placement of the field

Comment: Have you checked in woocommerce settings -> checkout that which payment method you want to display? And if you are using some function to display it then check that function's code if it has some hooks in it which is causing this?

Comment: The payment methods are selected from woocommerce settings page , but the field of the payment method is duplicated for each tab , i putted some images to show how the cheackout page is at the moment.

Comment: There might be some hooks which is displaying that duplicated payment methods in footer. Check where the payment methods template is included.

Comment: The footer files where checked . The checkout page is outdated as its 2.1.8 and the current core version of the woocommerce is 2.3.0. But i font see that a problem as it is working well as functionability.

Comment: Can you check that whether you have overidden the template or when updating you have upgraded the templates?

Comment: This looks like a theme issue. If you switch to a default theme I suspect it will go away. Or you can rename your theme's WooCommerce folder... that will temporarily disable all of your theme's custom templates. Could also be a CSS issue.

Comment: I don't know the solution but, the reason I find out is in `woocommerce/includes/wc-template-hooks.php` file line no: `174` and `175`.
They have attached one hook to multiple functions. Like `add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20 );`

Sorry, I am not sure if this fit is for the "answer".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure why the payment options are appearing on your Billing Details step (this will be down to how the theme is built); however I suspect this is happening because your theme has a `woocommerce` folder, and following one of the more recent WooCommerce updates (around `2.3.0`, I think), the WooCommerce theme files have changed slightly.

Previously, the payment options loop was in `/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php` in your theme folder. However, it was removed from this file and there are now two new files: `payment.php` and `payment-method.php`.

It's most likely that your *existing* `review-order.php` template contains the loop for displaying the available payment gateways, but WooCommerce sees that your theme doesn't have the `payment.php` file, so is helpfully using its default (located in `/plugins/woocommerce/templates`) - as a result, your checkout is doubling up on displaying the payment options.

**Try:**

Make a backup of your current `review-order.php` file, then copy `'review-order.php`, `payment.php` & `payment-method.php` from `/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/` to your theme folder: `[your-theme]/woocommerce/checkout/`.

Hopefully, you should no longer see the doubling-up of your payment methods. On the downside, you may well have to modify these files to bring them back in line with your theme.

Comment: Thanks for the help that worked like a charm . The theme was looping because payment.php

Answer (score 0):

Just rename this folder:

> /wp-content/themes/themename/woocommerce/**checkout**

It Is old code which is coming with theme.